# How to write unit tests throwing PDOException

Tags: php, unit-testing, pdo, phpunit

I have a class which handles a variety of database exceptions such as deadlocks and serialized transaction failures.  I'm trying to unit test it and ran into a roadblock.  An example of the code I want to test:

```
public function run(callable $callable)
{
    $this->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $callable();
        $this->commit();
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == '40P01' || $e->getCode() == '55P03') {
            // Deadlock (40P01) or lock not available (55P03).
            ...
        } 
        ...
    }
}
```

The documentation for `PDOException` says developers should not throw it themselves, and today I found out why when trying to write a unit test:

```
$obj->run(function() {
    ...
    throw new \PDOException('Deadlock', '40P01');
});
```

`A non well formed numeric value encountered`.  `PDOException` breaks the contract with `Exception` because exception codes must be int and `PDOException` creates string codes to match SQL standards.  They should have made a separate SQLCode property but instead reused the built-in code.  Therefore it's impossible to throw a `PDOException` with a real SQL error code within a unit test.

Next I tried to mock `PDOException`:

```
class PDOExceptionMock extends \PDOException
{
    protected $code = '';

    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    // This won't work because getCode is final
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }
}
```

This won't compile because 'Cannot override final method Exception->getCode()'.

Since I can't (and don't want to) recreate every type of deadlock and transaction error using a real database, **how can one write unit tests which need to throw `PDOException`s?**

Comment: Nitpicking: just because an automated test is implemented using PHPUnit does not make it a unit test. A test that runs code that talks to the database is not a unit test.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann, He doesn't want to touch the db, but test the logic which deals with deadlocks in isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to overwrite `getCode`. It is already there, so you need just to set the code. E.g.

```
class A {
    public function run(callable $callable)
    {
        try {
            $callable();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() == '40P01' || $e->getCode() == '55P03') {
                return 'expected';
            } 
            return 'unexpected';
        }
        return 'no caught';
    }
}

class StubException extends \PDOException {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->code = '40P01';
    }
}

$a = new A;

echo $a->run(function(){throw new StubException;});
```

echoes 'expected';

Comment: Ah, hadn't noticed we have direct access to the internal `code` property.  So obvious! Works for me. Thanks!